# Static variable is nil - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, static

I am doing some Objective-C exercises. I have two classes here one "main class" and one "sub class". What I needed is to get all the instances of my "main class" and put it in an array. I also wanted to use it in my "subclass". Below I give a small example.

```
@interface mainClass : NSObject
static NSArray *instanceObj;
@end
@implementation mainClass

//Here I used the designated initializer to initialize and add the instance to the     Array
@end


@interface subClass:mainClass
@end
@implementation subClass

//Here I want to use the Array to get instances of mainClass.
@end
```

If I do as the above example, I get a warning stating that the static array is not used and when getting data from Array it's nil. Also I tried declaring the static array in implementation file of "main Class", but I cannot use the Array in "Sub Class". Kindly provide me a solution and help me understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Move the `static` outside of the `@interface`, and into the .m file above the `@implementation`.
2. You obviously would need to make that `NSMutableArray`, not an `NSArray`.
3. Be forewarned that by adding objects to that array, that establishes a strong reference to those objects, and they won't be released until you remove them from the array.

As an aside, you might also want to conform to [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1), using `MainClass` and `SubClass` rather than `mainClass` and `subClass`. Better, use meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try moving it above the implementation. Also I am not going to edit the Array so I am using NSArray. Correct me if i am wrong. Also I will try to use weak reference or set the Array to nil once i have used it. Is it fine?

Comment: @RaajForu You won't be able to add objects to your array as they're allocated if the array is not mutable. And the process of adding an object to an array will, automatically, create a strong reference to the added object. There's no way to do this weakly (other than reverting to a C-language array and storing unsafe_unretained values, which is a horrible idea). Better to stick to array and have method for adding and removing objects (perhaps "register" and "unregister"). With no offense intended, what business problem are you trying to solve? This seems like a questionable pattern.

Comment: Thanks again. Now i understood why i should use a mutable Array. Also as it will add a strong reference to an object once it is initialized, i should use a mutable Array to add or remove them. I clearly understood now. Also If i use a static Mutable array above the implementation, will it be visible to subClass? I mean can i use it in sub Class? and for your question,Its not that big problem, I am just solving the exercises given in a book. I just completed learning the basics of Objective C.

Comment: Rob also I found out that, i can use static variable externally by using class methods'+' (Class scope). Is this a good approach? http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-static-variables-in-objective-c.html

Comment: Ok Understood. Also i tried to declare a static array in the implementation file. But I cannot use it in my sub class implementation file. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: yes I understand it before. I should use a non mutable copy for safety. But how to use them in subclass? I cannot get a reference to non mutable array in my sub class, I mean i cannot use the array outside main class.

Comment: @RaajForu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38789/discussion-between-rob-and-raaj-foru)